# Android: Get TargetSDKVersion in runtime

Tags: android

Can I get the used TargetSDKVersion in runtime?

This is due to the fact that the WebView in Android API 19> handles pixels differently than pre 19.

This is for a library and so I would not like to have the developer enter it manually.

My comment:
I am using my Nexus 5 API 21 Lollipop. Changing TargetSDKVersion changes the way javascript of the html reads the widths by a multiple of the screen density. I have just changed it to 14 then to 19, and I confirm this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[About target SDK version, look to the ApplicationInfo class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ApplicationInfo.html#targetSdkVersion) (get it from [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/dXLACRIizKc))

```
int version = 0;
IPackageManager pm = AppGlobals.getPackageManager();
try {
    ApplicationInfo applicationInfo = pm.getApplicationInfo(yourAppName, 0);
    if (applicationInfo != null) {
      version = applicationInfo.targetSdkVersion;
    }
}
```

**OR**

If we talk about device OS version

[Build class contain information about version](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html)

```
android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT
```

Comment: This returns the API version of the device.

Comment: It seems it is a great solution. I'll test it and set as answer when I confirm.

Comment: But, what is AppGlobals?

Answer (score 39):

In my case, I've done this

```
int targetSdkVersion = getApplicationContext().getApplicationInfo().targetSdkVersion;
```

Comment: This is much simpler than accepted answer and likely much more efficient. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

This is another way to get the `targetSdkVersion`of my application in runtime, using `Android Studio`:

```
try {
            PackageInfo packageInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
            int targetSdkVersion = packageInfo.applicationInfo.targetSdkVersion;

        }
        catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
```

the value of `targetSDKVersion` is defined into my `build.gradle` file

```
   defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.tuna.hello.androidstudioapplication"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 12
        versionName "1.0"
    }
```

Comment: Actually this is the exact approach as @Kirill's

Answer (score 3):

Having the following config in an Android Marshmallow (API 23) phone:

```
defaultConfig {
      applicationId "com.mytestapp"
      minSdkVersion 9
      targetSdkVersion 22
      versionCode 1
      versionName "1.0.0"
}
```

Another direct approach to get the **actual running app** [targetSdkVersion](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ApplicationInfo.html#targetSdkVersion) is:

```
Context mContext = getApplicationContext();
int targetSdkVersion = mContext.getApplicationInfo().targetSdkVersion; // Outputs 22
int mobileSdkVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT; // Outputs 23
```

Answer (score 0):

You can even set it in runtime:

```
        applicationInfo.targetSdkVersion = 32
```

This may work for example if some external api (WebView in my case) works differently depending of your app's target api and you need to restore previous behaviour on earlier platforms (in that case dont forget to wrap this with if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= xxx)