# Conditionally compile Android Java import statements

Tags: android

How can the import section of an Android Java program be conditionally compiled? I know we can conditionally compile classes in Java code using @TargetApi(). However, @TargetApi() does not work for the import section at the top of the java file.

In particular, I want to be able to ignore these import statement when compiling with compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion of 27. However, I want to keep these statements in the code and compile them when compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion are 30, or above. I wish the following code worked, but does not. Any suggestions?:

```
@TargetApi(30) // <== This statement does not work in this section, alternatives?
import android.net.wifi.WifiNetworkSuggestion
import static android.provider.Settings.ACTION_WIFI_ADD_NETWORKS;
import static android.provider.Settings.EXTRA_WIFI_NETWORK_LIST;
```

Comment: "I know we can conditionally compile classes in Java code using @TargetApi()" -- that is not what `@TargetApi` does. Beyond that, use `compileSdkVersion` of `30` all the time. Varying `targetSdkVersion` may make sense depending on what you are doing, but there is no reason to have more that one `compileSdkVersion`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As CommonsWare mentioned, using compileSdkVersion of 30, all the time, is correct in my circumstance. Also, surrounding particular classes with `@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.R)` and obtaining the target SDK version with `packageInfo.applicationInfo.targetSdkVersion` (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/30353224/3179186) satisfied my requirements.